# Writing a block-cyclic distributed matrix to a binary file

Tags: io, fortran, mpi, binaryfiles, scalapack

I am using Scalapack for diagonalizing matrices (25k × 25k) and need the eigenvectors. I am using pzlawrite to write out the distributed matrices to a file. But the speed of writing is quite slow in ASCII for such huge files. I suppose writing the output to a binary file would be much faster, but I am unable to get any examples for writing distributed matrices to a binary file in Fortran. Are there any inbuilt functions in scalapack to write out the distributed matrices in binary?

Comment: You did not ask a question. What is your question? If it is asking for an example, it is off-topic here. There are tutorials about parallel MPI I/O on the internet and even questions and answers here. You can also write each processes' part into a separate file in any format of your choice.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341860/mpi-io-reading-and-writing-block-cyclic-matrix